# Call function at native Error object's construction

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, prototype, v8

In the following code example :

```
var oldConstructor = Error.constructor;
Error.constructor = function() {
    console.log('Constructor');
    oldConstructor.apply(null, arguments);
};
var a = new Error('ok');
```

Why isn't `'Constructor'` printed ?

- How can I run a function every time a native `Error` object's constructor is called ?

The goal I'm trying to achieve is that rather than bubbling `Errors` up the callback chain of the different modules used in my code base (mongoose, express.js, ...etc), I just want every error to emit an event or call a method (maybe with an Observer pattern).

I'm trying to solve the problem this way rather than modifying every line of code creating a new `Error` object.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Error.constructor` is a reference to the `Function` function, because `Error` is a function and functions are constructed by `Function`.

You could have done:

```
var oldError = Error;
Error = function( arg ) {
    console.log('Constructor');
    return new oldError( arg );
};
```

But this is not guaranteed to work at all as modules could have stored a local reference to the `Error` constructor if they run before your code.

You could instead use the [uncaughtexception event](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception)

Comment: I thought about this solution but the linter on my editor said that the native Error object was read-only ... but after testing it turns out that it is not ! One more question, if my script is loaded first, wouldn't the module's local reference point to my modified Error object ?

Comment: @AwakeZoldiek yes they would

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick, helpful and easy answer !